# How do I execute a for loop statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

A pretty dumb question but I'm having trouble using a simple for loop, the i value is increased... I believe it is because the for loop has not met the required conditions.. but not sure what's going wrong

```
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0.0; i >= 5 / 360; i++) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

What went wrong: it does not print out anything...

Comment: Your condition is `i >= 5/360`. It never evaluates to true thus your loop doesn't execute even once.

Comment: What do you reckon the value of `5 / 350` is? Is it greater or lesser than 0?

Comment: 0 is never >= 5 / 360

Comment: i >= 5 / 360 gives false on 1st loop

Comment: yeah but even if i do less then it just prints out 0 and does not increment. the value of 5/360 is 0.01388888888

Comment: That's because `i` is incremented by one (`i++`) at the end of the first iteration so, upon the second iteration, the condition is `1 <= 5 / 360`, which evaluates to false and halts the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the condition becomes false in the first instance of the loop , 5/360 would be 0.013888  which is less than 0.0 , So it would not enter to append the text which you are trying to do. So the loop exists and the object text has only the initial value which was initialized.

For example , if you change the snippet as below it would generate a text:

```
for (i = 0.0; i <= 5/360 ; i++) {
  text = text +  "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
```

> The number is 0

So Kindly check the condition as per you requirement in order to generate text

Answer (score 2):

The condition for your loop is that `i >= 5 / 360`, which is not true when the loop starts. I recommend `i <= 5 / 360`

`++` increments by one. Since the expression to be evaluated is less than one, try incrementing by a lesser value using `+=`.

For example:

```js
var text = "";
for (var i = 0.0; i <= 5 / 360; i+=.005) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

For more info, see these JavaScript references:
[for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
[addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

> for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])

> Operator: x += y
>   Meaning:  x  = x + y

Answer (score 2):

there are 3 conditions in for loop as

> 1.initial value ex i=0
>
> 2.until which value loop should iterates ex i<=10
>
> 3.should vale has to be increment ++ or to be decreases -- after each iterations

in above given condition middle condition is wrong, it gets false value from its 1st iteration hence it is not able to complete even 1st iteration

```js
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0.0; i <= 5 / 360; i++) {
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  console.log(text)
}
```